# Basic flask template with sessions

Tags: python, mysql, security, flask, sqlalchemy

This Flask app, which makes use of SQLAlchemy, a MySQL server which is only reachable via SSH and Flask-Login, is the base on which I want to write an application which has login protected pages.

Registering users is a feature that I still have to write in a better way, but it works for now and testing purposes.

I'm posting this here because I want to be a 100% sure that my application is safe. I'm really curious to hear where I can improve, or if my application is reasonably safe. Cheers!

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, redirect, url_for, request
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy
from flask_login import LoginManager
from flask_login import login_required, login_user, current_user, UserMixin, logout_user
from pathlib import Path
from sshtunnel import SSHTunnelForwarder
import re
import paramiko
import bcrypt

SSH_IP = "example.com"
SSH_PORT = 32452
SSH_USER = "ssh_user_here"
SSH_KEY = paramiko.RSAKey.from_private_key_file(Path(r'filepath\key.key'))
SSH_REMOTE_BIND_IP = "127.0.0.1"
SSH_REMOTE_BIND_PORT = 3306

DB_IP = "127.0.0.1"
DB_USER = "db_username"
DB_PASSWORD = "db_password"

app = Flask(__name__)
app.secret_key = 'randomly generated string'
wsgi_app = app.wsgi_app

login_manager = LoginManager()
login_manager.init_app(app)
#Defines to which page the user is redirected when it's trying to reach a protected page
login_manager.login_view = 'Login'

#Start SSH tunnel so app is able to connect to database
tunnel = SSHTunnelForwarder(
    (SSH_IP, SSH_PORT),
    ssh_username=SSH_USER,
    ssh_pkey=SSH_KEY,
    remote_bind_address=(SSH_REMOTE_BIND_IP, SSH_REMOTE_BIND_PORT))
tunnel.start()
#Connect to the actual database
app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI'] = 'mysql+mysqlconnector://' + DB_USER + ':' + DB_PASSWORD + '@' + DB_IP +':' + str(tunnel.local_bind_port)+'/' + "database name"
db = SQLAlchemy(app)

class User(UserMixin, db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'Login'
    email = db.Column(db.String(200), unique=True, nullable=False, primary_key=True)
    password = db.Column(db.String(500))

    def get_id(self):
        return str(self.email)

    def check_password(self, password):
        return bcrypt.checkpw(password.encode('utf-8'), self.password.encode('utf-8'))

@login_manager.user_loader
def load_user(email):
    return User.query.filter_by(email=email).first()

def create_user(email, password):
    password = bcrypt.hashpw(password.encode('utf-8'), bcrypt.gensalt())
    password = password.decode('utf-8')
    new_user = User(email=email, password=password)
    db.session.add(new_user)
    db.session.commit()
    return    

@app.route('/')
@login_required
def index():
    return render_template('index.html', current_user=current_user.email)

@app.route('/login', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def login():
    #create_user("test@test.com", "testpassword123")

    # If the user is already logged in, redirect to index
    if current_user.is_authenticated:
        return redirect(url_for('index'))

    # Check if all the fields are filled in
    if request.method == 'POST' and 'email' in request.form and 'password' in request.form:
        email = request.form['email']
        password = request.form['password']

        # Check if email is valid.
        if re.match(r'[^@]+@[^@]+\.[^@]+', email):

            user = User.query.filter_by(email=email).first()

            if user and user.check_password(password):
                login_user(user)
                return redirect(url_for('index'))
            else:
                return render_template('login.html', msg="Unknown email//password combination entered!")
        else:
            return render_template('login.html', msg='Please enter a valid e-mail address' )
    else:
        return render_template('login.html', msg='Please fill in the form!')
    return render_template('login.html', msg="")

@app.route('/logout')
@login_required
def logout():
    logout_user()
    return redirect(url_for('login'))

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(host='0.0.0.0', port=80)
```

Comment: How do you plan to load the configuration for db/ssh on production? Will you pass environment variables or override the values on the file